# extjs problem sending extraParams to a restapi

Tags: extjs

I have a rest api which I want to read from extjs. These are the parameters expected by the rest api:

```
params = {
   sort: 'idlevel', 
   filter: {
      active: true, 
      idup: {
        'null': 0
      }
   }
}
```

as you can see it is a very simple Javascript object. These parameters works like a charm from another application built with Reactjs. From Extjs store I'm sending them from my store like this:

```
...

 proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',

        headers: {
           'Accept': '*/*',
           'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
           'Content-Type': 'application/json',
           'Authorization': localStorage.token
        },

        extraParams: {
          sort: 'idlevel', 
          filter: {
             active: true, 
             idup: {
               'null': 0
             }
          }
       }

   ...
```

The thing is this is returning a Validation Failed error. When I go into the browser's network history I see these Query String parameters:

```
_dc: 1556221645266
filter: [object Object]
filter: true
sort: idlevel
page: 1
start: 0
limit: 25
```

I don't know why Extjs turn the javascript object in the `extraParams` into this weird thing. So my question is: how can I tell Extjs to assume these parameters the right way? Am I missing something trivial here?

UPDATE:
This is the Query String output when using react:

```
sort: idlevel
filter[active]: true
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If query string in react is like this:

```
sort: idlevel
filter[active]: true
```

Then in extjs ajax proxy should be:

```
    var myStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
        autoLoad: true,
        fields: ['a'],
        noCache: true,
        remoteSort: false,
        remoteFilter: false,
        pageSize: 0,
        proxy: {
            url: "http://example.xyz",
            noCache: false,
            type: 'ajax',
            headers: {
                'Accept': '*/*',
                'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Authorization': localStorage.token
            },
            extraParams: {
                sort: 'idlevel',
                'filter[active]': true
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You're sending an Object through the url, which it expects to be plain text, my suggestion is to use `JSON.stringify()` in your objects, something like this

```
    extraParams: {
      sort: 'idlevel', 
      filter: JSON.stringify({
         active: true, 
         idup: {
           'null': 0
         }
      })
   }
```

Then in your back-end you can transform the string again in an object

Comment: Can you show how your server expects the data to be?

Comment: I did, is the very first Javascript object in the question

Comment: Sry didn't saw, well, I guess it should be working if you transform  it  again to an object in the back-end with something like `JSON.parse(yourparam.filter)`

Comment: the rest api is not mine, it is public, so I can not modify it